# Accessing $scope variable from another method in the same controller Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I  call/access `$scope.mydata` from another method in the same controller in Angularjs?

My scenario is

```
.controller("myCtryl", function($scope,  $http) {
  $scope.functionA = function(){
     $scope.data = "some data";
  }
  $scope.functionB = function(){
     //access $scope.data here//
  }

}
```

Comment: yeah just access it there, what is the issue

Comment: I'm getting empty when I tried to alert() it.

Comment: @user3569641 Have you actually *called* `functionA`?

Comment: You must be trying to access `$scope.data` in the other function before the previous function sets the value on it asyncronously. Currently your question is too unclear for us to provide a definitive answer for your issue,

Comment: yeah. thank you. @PSL. I was trying to access it before the previous function sets value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to access `$scope` in that function.

```
.controller("myCtryl", function($scope,  $http) {
  $scope.functionA = function(){
     $scope.data = "some data";
  }
  $scope.functionB = function(){
     $scope.data //this id valid
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access `$scope.data` in `functionB` the same way you access it in `functionA`. It will work. The `$scope` variable is in the same lexical scope for both functions.