# AngularJs access scope variable in another function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and have this following piece of code that I need to edit.

```
 scope.findData = [];
 scope.clientId;
 scope.identityDocuments_a = [];


scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a = function(clientID){  
        resourceFactory.clientResource.getAllClientDocuments({clientId: clientID, anotherresource: 'identifiers'}, function(data){
                scope.identityDocuments_a = data;
            });            
        };

        scope.findOptions = function(value){
            var i;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
resourceFactory.clientResource.getAllClientsWithoutLimit({displayName: value, orderBy : 'id', officeId : scope.group.officeId, sortOrder : 'ASC', orphansOnly : true}, function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data.pageItems);
                  for (i = 0; i <= data.pageItems.length; i++) {

                 scope.clientId = data.pageItems[i].id;
                 scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a(scope.clientId);
                    //<- I want to access scope.identityDocuments_a here
                }
                scope.findData = data.pageItems;

              });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Both these functions are under the same controller.
I looked at [Accessing $scope variable from another method in the same controller Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139972/accessing-scope-variable-from-another-method-in-the-same-controller-angularjs) but it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which variable are you not able to access?  The clientID in getClientIdentityDocuments_a()?  If that's the problem, try `clientId: scope.clientID`

Comment: I am unable to access scope.identityDocuments_a. I tried alert(scope.identityDocuments_a.toSource()); and it just showed []

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see the problem.  Your getClientIdentityDocuments_a() is using a callback function.  THe asynchronous data retrieval happens seperately and so the value is not set by the time you want to use it.  You can fix this by returning a promise

```
scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a = function(clientID){
        var defer = $q.defer();  
        resourceFactory.clientResource.getAllClientDocuments(
                  {clientId: clientID, 
                   anotherresource: 'identifiers'}, function(data){
                scope.identityDocuments_a = data;
                defer.resolve(data);
            });            
            return defer.promise;
        };
```

and then, to use the data in your second function:

```
scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a(scope.clientId).then(function(documents) {
       // at this point, the scope.identityDocuments_a should be available,
       // but you could just set it here, since the document variable is
       // returning the same thing
    console.dir(scope.identityDocuments_a) // should have the returned data
    console.dir(documents)                 // should be the same as above
});
// Here, the documents will NOT be available, because this executes before
// the promise is resolved
console.dir(scope.identityDocuments_a) // [] or undefined
```

**UPDATE:**  To clarify, if in getClientIdentityDocuments_a you were to directly assign the variable, such as

```
scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a = function(clientID){
        scope.identityDocuments_a = some_document;
};
```

You would not need the promise and your code would work.  But since you are retrieving the data from an asynchronous source, your second function is trying to use the data before the value has been set.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. But I don't quite follow what is scope.getClientIdentityDocuments_a(scope.clientId).then(function(document) { }); 
for?

Comment: I've turned the getClientIdentityDocuments_a() function into a promise that only resolves after the asynchronous call which updates the identityDocuments_a variable is completed.  If you do anything with the variable before the asynchronous call has returned its data, the variable will be unchanged.  the `.then()` syntax can be used with any promise in lieu of callback syntax, and it just waits until told the promise is resolved (in this case by the `defer.resolve()`) before it executes.

Comment: I have tried your code but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried 
alert(scope.identityDocuments_a.toSource());
before the return statement and it showed [].

Comment: Yes, it would show that, because the value has not yet been returned from the resource.  When working with asynchronous retrievals, the code continues chugging away while the retrieval is happening.  The `return defer.promise;` is happening immediately after kicking off the data retrieval, before the data has been set.  Is there any chance you can give me enough code that I can create a working fiddle?

Comment: @coderGeek, I made more edits to the answer.  Does any of that help?  Do you know how promises and asynchronous calls work?

Comment: I am quite new to AngularJS and I don't know how promises and asynchronous calls work

Comment: Okay.  you might want to start [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).  The basic idea is that instead of stopping program execution when making a possibly costly call (e.g. data retrieval over the internet), the program should continue with a token in place of the data.  Then when the data is returned, the token executes and the data is available.  But it's easy to get tripped up trying to access the data directly before it is available.  You'll need to get a solid understanding of that if your code is going to work.  Good luck, and let me know if I can help